# Issues with a tag system's creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, tags

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/tagging-scratch-rails/) to create some custom tags. I the instructions excepted for the AJAX and Foundation part since I haven't built my website this way. I'm experiencing an issue with the "tag research" part when you only need to click on a tag to see all posts about the tag, Rails tells me the following:

```
undefined method `articles' for #<Tag:0x007f0a690eeb40>
```

Here are my files adapted from the tutorial:

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploader :image, ArticleUploader
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :titre, use: :slugged
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

  def all_tags=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(',').map do |name|
      Tag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end

  def all_tags
    self.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end

  def self.tagged_with(name)
   Tag.find_by_name!(name).articles # Issue comes from here
  end

end
```

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

**tagging.rb**

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
 get 'tags/:tag', to: 'articles#index', as: "tag"
 resources :articles
```

Please ask if you need to see something else

As you can see, i simply used my 'Article' model that already existed when starting the tutorial, so I used 'articles' instead of 'posts' as the author asked. I can't find anything related on Google and i'm not working with any IDE right now so I have no clue about what to do..

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: In the `Tag` model change your association `has_many :tags, through: :taggings` to: `has_many :articles, through: :taggings` and try. You should not face issue.

Comment: Thank you it worked ! I knew it was obvious yet I couldn't find where I did the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Tag` model you are trying to associate `tags` only means you are associating itself. So change your association

```
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

to:

```
has_many :articles, through: :taggings
```

and try. You should not face issue.